# Wordpress Orderby wont order posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to order my products by discount-amount.
I have saved the discount as a number in my post-meta called "discount", but when I use the following code:

```
$productArgs = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'meta_key'          => 'discount',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_decimal',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'meta_type'         => 'DECIMAL',
);

$test = $productArgs;

$products = get_posts($productArgs);
```

The products are displayed like: 0%, 50%, 55%, 28%.
Even if I change the `order` to ASC, nothing happens to the output.

I have also tried `'orderby' => 'meta_value'`, and without the `'meta_type'`.

Does anyone have an idea what can be causing this?

**EDIT:**

I figured out my mistake.. My posts were added to an array, with the ID as the array-key, which sorted by post-ID.

Comment: Must not `'orderby'=>'discount'`? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/#source  And `'meta_value'=>'decimal'`? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/

Comment: what about meta_query? 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: @NewUser - I only need to order by the meta_value - it doesn't matter if it is 0 or 100, so I don't see how I should use a meta_query to do that.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions - I don't know what you mean by that comment..

Answer (score 0):

If discount fields are all numbers, try `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` and remove the `meta_type` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the meta key for orderby parameter like,

```
query_posts(
    array(  'post_type' => 'product',
            'order'     => 'ASC',
            'meta_key' => 'discount',
            'orderby'   => 'meta_value', //or 'meta_value_num'
            'meta_query' => array(
                                array('key' => 'order_in_archive',
                                      'value' => 'some_value'
                                )
                            )
    )
);
```

Hope this will work.